# Multiple Roles Filters in Laravel Controller Constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, filter, acl, before-filter

I have a question about filtering a controller and its actions for multiple user roles. Lets say i have a controller named MyController :

```
public class MyController extends \BaseController
{
   public static function index()
   {
   }

   public static function show()
   {
   }

   public static function create()
   {
   }

   public static function store()
   {
   }

   public static function other()
   {
   }
}
```

And i have 2 filters for each roles, named admin and staff :

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    // Lines of code to get role
    if($role != 'admin') return View::make('errors.401');
});

Route::filter('staff', function()
{
    // Lines of code to get role
    if($role != 'staff') return View::make('errors.401');
});
```

Then, i'm trying to use beforeFilter on the constructor of MyController :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('admin', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'create', 'store']]);
    $this->beforeFilter('staff', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
}
```

When I added the first beforeFilter, it works as I expected (when I logged in to my application as staff, I cannot access the index, show, create, and store methods). But when I added the second filter and logged in as staff again, I cannot access the index and show actions, which is I expected to be accessible by staff.

My questions are, is it possible to define filters for multiple roles in the constructor of a controller? (In this case, I want to make action index and show accessible by admin and staff, but create and store only accessible by admin) And if it is possible, how could I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have Admin can access all feature, and staff can access everything except "show"

This is the controller

```
class MyController extends \BaseController
{
   public function __construct(){
       $this->beforeFilter('admin', ['only' => ['show']]);
   }    
   public function index()
   {
    echo "index";
   }

   public function show()
   {
    echo "show";
   }
}
```

See in your last post, you are using public class, I believe in PHP you will just need class, in function better don't use static.

Here is the filters.php

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    // Lines of code to get role
    if($role != 'admin') return "This is only for admin";
});
```

In the routes.php

```
Route::get("/my", "MyController@index");
Route::get("/show", "MyController@show");
```

Then try to login as admin, you will can access "index" and "show"
Then try to login as staff, you will can access "index" but cannot access "show"

Answer (score 1):

First you should make a controller that should handle access control ... as below

Acl Controller

```
 class ACLController extends \BaseController {

        /**
         * admin access control list
         * @return array
         */
        private function adminACL() {
            return array(
                'users' => array(
                    'users',
                    'users.show',
   //similar access list for admin users

                ),



      );
        }



/**
     * staff access control list
     * @return array
     */
    private function staffACL() {
        return array(

            'staff' => array(
                'staff',
                'staff.index',
//similar access list for staff user

            ),

        );
    }

//Method that check access of related user

    /**
     * check access level
     * @param string $value
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasAccessLevel($value) {
        $user = //get user role here
        if ($user->roles == 'staff') {
            return TRUE;

            } elseif ($user->roles == 'admin') {
                $newAcl = array();
                foreach ($this->adminACL() as $aclBreak) {
                    foreach ($aclBreak as $acl) {
                        $newAcl[] = $acl;
                    }
                }
                if (!in_array($value, $newAcl)) {
                    return FALSE;
                } else {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            } else {
                $newAcl = array();
                foreach ($this->staffACL() as $aclBreak) {
                    foreach ($aclBreak as $acl) {
                        $newAcl[] = $acl;
                    }
                }
                if (!in_array($value, $newAcl)) {
                    return FALSE;
                } else {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

Filter the access route...

```
Route::filter('hasAccess',function($route,$request,$value){
    try{
        $Routeacl = new App\Controllers\ACLController();        
        if(!$acl->hasAccessLevel($value))
        {            
            return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard')->withErrors(array(Lang::get('en.user_noaccess')));
        }
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
});
```

And then in your route just check if it has access

```
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'index', 'before' => 'hasAccess:index', 'uses' => 'MyController@Index'));
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Is an admin always a staff member? If so - you could just do this:

```
Route::filter('staff', function()
{
    // Lines of code to get role
    if(($role != 'staff') && ($role != 'admin'))return View::make('errors.401');
});
```

Comment: Nope, admin and staff are 2 different roles and not related to each other.